# Discord.js Replit, cannot get my bot to respond to commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, replit

I am currently developing a Discord bot for replit, and I am able to get it to post and even get it to send an intro message when joining a server, however whenever I try to get it to respond to a command I type it won't respond. The message for the first one client.on guild create works. However the client.on for async message will not work.

This is what I have so far.

```
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: 32767 });

//const Discord = require('discord.js');
const keepAlive = require('./server');
require("dotenv").config();
//const client = new Discord.Client();
//const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const config = require('./package.json');
const prefix = '!';
const guild = "";


client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Jp Learn Online');
});

// let defaultChannel = "";
// guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel) => {
//     if(channel.type == "text" && defaultChannel == "") {
//     if(channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES")) {
//         defaultChannel = channel;
//         }
//     }
// })
//defaultChannel.send("This is a test message I should say this message when I join");


//if(guild.systemChannelId != null) return guild.systemChannel.send("This is a test message I should say this message when I join"), console.log('Bot entered new Server.')

// client.on('guildCreate', (g) => {
// const channel = g.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.type === 'GUILD_TEXT' && channel.permissionsFor(g.me).has('SEND_MESSAGES'))
// channel.send("This is a test message I should say this message when I join");
// });

client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
  guild.systemChannel.send('this message wil print')
});

client.on('message', async message => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/); // This splits our code into to allow multiple commands.
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'jhelp') {
    message.channel.send('こんにちは、私はDiscordロボットです。始めたいなら、!jhelp タイプしてください。 \n\n Hello I am a discord bot built to help learn the Japanese language! \n\n If you want to access a japanese dictionary type !dictionary \n\n If you would like to learn a random Japanese Phrase type !teachme \n\n If you would like to answer a challenge question type !challenge1 through 5 each different numbered challnege will ask a different question \n (ie. !challenge1) this will ask the first question.')


  }
```

please note. the lower parts of the code are simply commands. That expand further from jhelp I want to know mainly why my second client.on with messages wont work specifically in the context of working with replit.

Thanks for the help in advance.

I expected that maybe changing intents might work, I even went into the discord developer portal, and enabled options, and am still not able to get it working.

Comment: Why are you trying to use all intents when you only need MessageConent

Answer (score 0):

After Discord separated out the message intent as a privileged one, the bit field you need to use for all intents has changed. You need to use 131071.

I.e.

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: 131071 });

//const Discord = require('discord.js');
const keepAlive = require('./server');
require("dotenv").config();
//const client = new Discord.Client();
//const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const config = require('./package.json');
const prefix = '!';
const guild = "";


client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Jp Learn Online');
});

// let defaultChannel = "";
// guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel) => {
//     if(channel.type == "text" && defaultChannel == "") {
//     if(channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES")) {
//         defaultChannel = channel;
//         }
//     }
// })
//defaultChannel.send("This is a test message I should say this message when I join");


//if(guild.systemChannelId != null) return guild.systemChannel.send("This is a test message I should say this message when I join"), console.log('Bot entered new Server.')

// client.on('guildCreate', (g) => {
// const channel = g.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.type === 'GUILD_TEXT' && channel.permissionsFor(g.me).has('SEND_MESSAGES'))
// channel.send("This is a test message I should say this message when I join");
// });

client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
  guild.systemChannel.send('this message wil print')
});

client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/); // This splits our code into to allow multiple commands.
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'jhelp') {
    message.channel.send('こんにちは、私はDiscordロボットです。始めたいなら、!jhelp タイプしてください。 \n\n Hello I am a discord bot built to help learn the Japanese language! \n\n If you want to access a japanese dictionary type !dictionary \n\n If you would like to learn a random Japanese Phrase type !teachme \n\n If you would like to answer a challenge question type !challenge1 through 5 each different numbered challnege will ask a different question \n (ie. !challenge1) this will ask the first question.')


  }
```

Comment: I tried this however, this didnt seem to fix my problem. Specifically the second client.on here doesnt seem to be operating any of my commands, I can actually get the first client on to work and the bot will post the test message on a server it joins.

Comment: Second `.on` should be `messageCreate`. I've edited my post to reflect this. Sorry for not noticing earlier!

Answer (score -2):

Yes! its the problem with your intents, for guildMemberAdd/Remove you require **GuildMembers** intents

Comment: `32767` does include the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent so this answer is incorrect.